# How to be notified when an error occurs in a file running with a cron Job?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, push-notification, cron

I'm building a new WordPress website, There will be a php file that is executed daily using a cron job.

I'm thinking of creating a new section in admin dashboard to show the new errors that may occur from that script.

One of the ideas is creating a text file and throw the errors there and separate between them with a new line or a comma, Then fetch these errors to that section.

Using `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fread()`, Or using `error_log()`.

How to do that?

Is there is a better way to be notified, When an error occurs?

Comment: A “real” cron, or the pseudo-cron functionality WP provides? Real cron can easily be configured to send the output via mail for example. But if you want to show it inside the WP admin dashboard, writing to a file might be the better option. I would perhaps rather not write it to the database - because then you got no proper logging if there ever is a database problem that causes the error to begin with; that something suddenly goes wrong when just writing to the file system is less likely.

Comment: @CBroe, That's great thanks, I have another question if you don't mind, How to notify the admin that there is a new error?

Comment: Notify directly, as in send them a mail as soon as something happens, or just by alerting them that there’s new entries when they enter the backend? For the former, simply add code that sends out an mail in the error case to your script that is run per cron, in the same place where you implement the logging of those errors as well. Start with a hard-coded recipient mail address maybe; you could of course try and read the admin email from the WordPress database, but again, I would keep it as simple as possible, so that it doesn’t fail in cases where the database actually is the error reason.

Comment: @CBroe, I don't mean to send them to an email, I'm talking about something similar to stackoverflow notifications for example, So when a new error is thrown to that file, A number with a red background is shown on the admin menu, Like when there is a new wordpress version update

Comment: Well then you need something that reads your logged error messages, and also stores when the admin was _last_ notified about errors (that you can determine when an error is actually “new”.) But this is getting rather broad, so you’ll have to do some research on how/were to properly place this within the WordPress backend yourself.